# Understanding generic parameters in an abstract class

Tags: kotlin

In the Kotlin docs, they show how to include type parameters:

```
class Box<T>(t: T) {
    var value = t
}
```

This is a simple example. But I've come across one that looks like this:

```
abstract class SomeAdapter<T, WH: SomeViewHolder>(private val viewModel: SomeModel<T>?) {

}
```

How do I interpret this? Do I interpret this as:

> SomeAdapter takes two parameters when it's instantiated - a T and a WH. And the constructor takes a viewModel.

Comment: Do the answer solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

As you already referenced, this class has two generic types: `T` and `WH`. The latter does specify an [upper bound](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) `SomeViewHolder` which will only allow sub types of that upper bound to be used as the generic type `WH`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your title goes:

> Understanding generic parameters in an abstract class

the question at hand is: Would it be different (regarding the generic types) if `SomeAdapter` would not be abstract. The answer is: No.

In this particular example `T` can be `Any?` and `WH` can be any subclass of `SomeAdapter` or `SomeAdapter` itself (if `SomeAdapter` is not abstract).

The types of `T` and `WH` are fixed at compile time (see [Type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure)).

So, you have to see generics like a variable for a type.